# Direct invitation or simple msg stanza doesn't get sent through openfire if connected to room using muc

Tags: openfire

We are trying to build a chat application in MVC using strophe.js.
We have created a chat room using rest api and want another user to join the room.

We tried to send a direct invitation using below code. but somehow, stanzas are not getting generated and sent. even no error is thrown.
Even, we tried to send a simple message to another user. but that also doesn't show up in network panel in firefox or reach to another user.

We have added other user to the roster and vice versa with both subscription. but somehow, none of the messages get sent.
We added mediated invitation before this stanza. it gets sent; I mean no error is received. but doesn't get received on another end.

could it be, we are using an old version of strophe.js? we are using one from professional XMPP book source code.
we actually tried very latest from GitHub. but then also there was no luck

will appreciate any help! thanks in advance

```
    XMPPComm.connection.send($msg({
    from: XMPPComm.User_Id,
    to: to + '@servername'
    })
    .c('x', {xmlns: "jabber:x:conference",jid: RoomId
    }));

    var message = $msg({
    to: to + 'servername',"type": "chat"    })
    .c('body').t('Room Joining invitation by sachin ,' + RoomId).up()
    .c('active', { xmlns: "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates" });
```

somehow, our chat on existing chat room created works fine.

Regards,
pravin